libfprint undefined reference to `fp_init`
I'm attempting to write a C program using libfprint, and it throws an undefined reference error when I attempt to compile something like:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libfprint-2/fprint.h>

int main() {
    if (fp_init() != 0) {
        printf("Failed to initialize libfprint\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("libfprint initialized successfully!!\n");
    }
}

This is how I complied it:
cc -o my_fprint_app my_fprint_app.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libfprint-2)

How can I solve this?
I was expecting to see one of the print statements, but instead the program didn't even compile.

I don't see a fp_init() listed in the library's API documentation (assuming this is the same library)...

Similar to what @Shawn mentioned, I don't see that function anywhere in the headers for libfprint2. I do see it used in some repos that seem to use an older libfprint however. It would be helpful for people if you included the error message your compiler is emitting

I don't see it in the supplied example programs I looked at either. What made you think this function exists?

@Shawn you might take a look here. I don't know if that is an older version or some other library.
